# JSON Dataset structure

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, dataset

I am creating mysql records into json array, but there seems to be some issue with json dataset. PFB code :-

JSON output coming:-

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "Coupon_ID": "ABC1",
    "Campaign_ID": "353",
    "Campaign_Name": "Test1",
    "Title": "Test1",
    "Description": "Test1",
    "Category": "Test1",
    "Type": "Coupon",
    "Type_Value": "1231",
    "Tracking_URL": "http://abc1.com",
    "Added_Date": "2016-07-13",
    "Expiry_Date": "2016-07-28"
}][
{
    "ID": "2",
    "Coupon_ID": "ABC2",
    "Campaign_ID": "3532",
    "Campaign_Name": "Test2",
    "Title": "Test2",
    "Description": "Test2",
    "Category": "Test2",
    "Type": "Coupon",
    "Type_Value": "1232",
    "Tracking_URL": "http://abc2.com",
    "Added_Date": "2016-07-13",
    "Expiry_Date": "2016-07-28"
}]
```

I want something like this :-

```
 [{
    "ID": "1",
    "Coupon_ID": "ABC1",
    "Campaign_ID": "353",
    "Campaign_Name": "Test1",
    "Title": "Test1",
    "Description": "Test1",
    "Category": "Test1",
    "Type": "Coupon",
    "Type_Value": "1231",
    "Tracking_URL": "http://abc1.com",
    "Added_Date": "2016-07-13",
    "Expiry_Date": "2016-07-28"
}
{
    "ID": "2",
    "Coupon_ID": "ABC2",
    "Campaign_ID": "3532",
    "Campaign_Name": "Test2",
    "Title": "Test2",
    "Description": "Test2",
    "Category": "Test2",
    "Type": "Coupon",
    "Type_Value": "1232",
    "Tracking_URL": "http://abc2.com",
    "Added_Date": "2016-07-13",
    "Expiry_Date": "2016-07-28"
}]
```

I mean [] these brackets instead of coming for each records, these should come only once.

PHP Code :-

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "couponsdeals";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $apikey = $_GET['API_KEY'];
    $sql = "SELECT  AFF_ID FROM api WHERE API_KEY= '$apikey' ";

    //$sql1= "SELECT  ID,Coupon_ID,Campaign_ID,Campaign_Name,Title,Description,Category,Type,Type_Value,Tracking_URL,Added_Date,Expiry_Date FROM couponcode_table ";

    $sql1 = "SELECT  * FROM couponcode_table ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
    if ($result) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data = $row["AFF_ID"];
            if ($result1) {
                while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $data1 = $row1["Tracking_URL"];
                    $mydata = explode("&", $data1);
                    if (isset($mydata[2])) {
                        $json1 = array();
                        $mydata2 = $mydata[0] . "&aff_id=" . $data . "&" . $mydata[2];
                        $values = array(
                            'ID' => $row1['ID'],
                            'Coupon_ID' => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                            'Campaign_ID' => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                            'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                            'Title' => $row1['Title'],
                            'Description' => $row1['Description'],
                            'Category' => $row1['Category'],
                            'Type' => $row1['Type'],
                            'Type_Value' => $row1['Type_Value'],
                            'Tracking_URL' => $mydata2,
                            'Added_Date' => $row1['Added_Date'],
                            'Expiry_Date' => $row1['Expiry_Date']

                        );
                        array_push($json1, $values);
                        echo json_encode($json1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    } else {
                        $json = array();
                        $mydata1 = $mydata[0] . "&aff_id=" . $data;
                        $value = array(
                            'ID' => $row1['ID'],
                            'Coupon_ID' => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                            'Campaign_ID' => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                            'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                            'Title' => $row1['Title'],
                            'Description' => $row1['Description'],
                            'Category' => $row1['Category'],
                            'Type' => $row1['Type'],
                            'Type_Value' => $row1['Type_Value'],
                            'Tracking_URL' => $mydata1,
                            'Added_Date' => $row1['Added_Date'],
                            'Expiry_Date' => $row1['Expiry_Date']
                        );
                        array_push($json, $value);
                        echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif (!$result) {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: don't use json_encode in the loop. Instead, store the array in some temporary array $resultArray[] = array(...) . After loop, do echo json_encode($resultArray)

Comment: just initialize $json1 = array(); outside loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize/echo your JSON array outside the while loops:

```
$json = array();
while(....) {
    while(....) {
        //.......
        array_push($json, $value);
        //.......
    }
}
echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just change your code, try out this code, hope you will get expected out put.

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "couponsdeals";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$apikey = $_GET['API_KEY'];
$sql = "SELECT  AFF_ID FROM api WHERE API_KEY= '$apikey' ";

//$sql1= "SELECT  ID,Coupon_ID,Campaign_ID,Campaign_Name,Title,Description,Category,Type,Type_Value,Tracking_URL,Added_Date,Expiry_Date FROM couponcode_table ";

$sql1= "SELECT  * FROM couponcode_table ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

if ($result) {

    // output data of each row

    $json = array();


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $data= $row["AFF_ID"];

        if($result1){

            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {


                $data1=$row1["Tracking_URL"];



                $mydata = explode("&",$data1);


                if(isset($mydata[2])){

                    $mydata2= $mydata[0]."&aff_id=".$data."&".$mydata[2];

                    $values =array(
                            'ID' => $row1['ID'],
                            'Coupon_ID' => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                            'Campaign_ID' => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                            'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                            'Title' => $row1['Title'],
                            'Description' => $row1['Description'],
                            'Category' => $row1['Category'],
                            'Type' => $row1['Type'],
                            'Type_Value' => $row1['Type_Value'],
                            'Tracking_URL' =>$mydata2,
                            'Added_Date' => $row1['Added_Date'],
                            'Expiry_Date' => $row1['Expiry_Date']
                        );


                    array_push($json, $values);

                } else {

                    $mydata1= $mydata[0]."&aff_id=".$data;

                    $value =array(
                            'ID' => $row1['ID'],
                            'Coupon_ID' => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                            'Campaign_ID' => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                            'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                            'Title' => $row1['Title'],
                            'Description' => $row1['Description'],
                            'Category' => $row1['Category'],
                            'Type' => $row1['Type'],
                            'Type_Value' => $row1['Type_Value'],
                            'Tracking_URL' =>$mydata1,
                            'Added_Date' => $row1['Added_Date'],
                            'Expiry_Date' => $row1['Expiry_Date']
                        );

                        array_push($json, $value);

                }

            }

        }
    }

    echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);    
}
elseif(!$result) {

    echo "0 results";

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you intend to get all the data generated within the loop, you may need to just store all the data in a variable and differ the output `echo $whatever;` till the end of your Script and outside of the Loops. That way you are sure to take all your Data along in one go... The slightly modified and commented *code of yours* below illustrates it all better

```
    <?php
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $servername     = "localhost";
        $username       = "root";
        $password       = "";
        $dbname         = "couponsdeals";

        // CREATE A VARIABLE THAT WOULD HOLD ALL THE DATA (ARRAY GENERATED IN THE LOOP)
        // INITIALIZE IT TO THE DEFAULT "FAILURE" MESSAGE..."0 Results"
        // THAT WAY; YOU WOULDN'T NEED ANY else if() CLAUSE...
        $jsonData       = array("message"=> "0 results");

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $apikey     = $_GET['API_KEY'];
        $sql        = "SELECT  AFF_ID FROM api WHERE API_KEY= '$apikey' ";
        $sql1       = "SELECT  * FROM couponcode_table ";
        $result     = $conn->query($sql);
        $result1    = $conn->query($sql1);
        $json       = array();
        $json1      = array();

        if ($result) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data   = $row["AFF_ID"];
                if($result1){
                    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $data1  = $row1["Tracking_URL"];
                        $mydata = explode("&",$data1);

                        if(isset($mydata[2])){
                            $json1      = array();
                            $mydata2    = $mydata[0]."&aff_id=".$data."&".$mydata[2];
                            $values     = array(
                                'ID'            => $row1['ID'],
                                'Coupon_ID'     => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                                'Campaign_ID'   => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                                'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                                'Title'         => $row1['Title'],
                                'Description'   => $row1['Description'],
                                'Category'      => $row1['Category'],
                                'Type'          => $row1['Type'],
                                'Type_Value'    => $row1['Type_Value'],
                                'Tracking_URL'  => $mydata2,
                                'Added_Date'    => $row1['Added_Date'],
                                'Expiry_Date'   => $row1['Expiry_Date']
                            );
                            // PUSH DATA TO THE $json1 VARIABLE
                            // AND DO NOT OUTPUT IT HERE YET... DIFFER IT
                            // TO THE END OF THE SCRIPT.
                            array_push($json1, $values);

                        }else{
                            $json       = array();
                            $mydata1    = $mydata[0]."&aff_id=".$data;
                            $value      = array(
                                'ID'            => $row1['ID'],
                                'Coupon_ID'     => $row1['Coupon_ID'],
                                'Campaign_ID'   => $row1['Campaign_ID'],
                                'Campaign_Name' => $row1['Campaign_Name'],
                                'Title'         => $row1['Title'],
                                'Description'   => $row1['Description'],
                                'Category'      => $row1['Category'],
                                'Type'          => $row1['Type'],
                                'Type_Value'    => $row1['Type_Value'],
                                'Tracking_URL'  => $mydata1,
                                'Added_Date'    => $row1['Added_Date'],
                                'Expiry_Date'   => $row1['Expiry_Date']
                            );
                            // PUSH DATA TO THE $json VARIABLE
                            // AND DO NOT OUTPUT IT HERE YET... DIFFER IT
                            // TO THE END OF THE SCRIPT...
                            array_push($json, $value);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            // NOW; OVERRIDE THE $jsonData VARIABLE WE CREATED ABOVE
            // AND CREATE 2 ELEMENTS WITHIN IT 'json1' & 'json2'
            // TO HOLD THE VALUES GENERATED WITHIN THE IF & ELSE CLAUSE RESPECTIVELY:SET ITS VALUE TO THE $json
            $json       = (!empty($json))  ? $json  : array("message"=>"Empty Data-set for json");
            $json1      = (!empty($json1)) ? $json1 : array("message"=>"Empty Data-set for json1");

            // ASSIGN DATA FROM $json & $json1 TO THE $jsonData ARRAY...
            $jsonData   = array(
                "json"  => $json,
                "json1" => $json1,
            );
        }
        // NO NEED FOR ELSE CLAUSE BECAUSE IF THE "IF CLAUSE" DOES NOT RUN;
        // WE HAVE A DEFAULT FOR THE $jsonData WHICH HAS A MESSAGE KEY
        // CONTAINING THE DEFAULT MESSAGE WITHIN AN ARRAY...

        // CLOSE DB CONNECTION 
        $conn->close();

        // ECHO OUT THE JSON-ENCODED DATA AND EXIT THE SCRIPT USING DIE...
        die( json_encode($jsonData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES) );
```